# Assign global variable from async method using c#

Tags: c#

I have an async method whereby i want to pull some data and assign to global variable for use in another method.
Below is the method:

```
private async void getgoogleplususerdataSer(string access_token)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + access_token;

            client.CancelPendingRequests();
            HttpResponseMessage output = await client.GetAsync(urlProfile);

            if (output.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string outputData = await output.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                GoogleUserOutputData serStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleUserOutputData>(outputData);

                if (serStatus != null)
                {
                    gName = serStatus.name;
                    gEmail = serStatus.email;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catching the exception
        }
    }
```

The variables gName and gEmail have already been declared.
I want to use the variables to register user using the following logic:

```
 protected void RegisterGoogleUser()
    {
        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string sql5 = "SELECT Email FROM Members where Email=@gEmail";
        using (SqlConnection con5 = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(sql5, con5))
            {
                con5.Open();
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gEmail", gEmail);
                Object result = cmd5.ExecuteScalar();
                con5.Close();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "This e-mail is already registered. If you forgot your password, use forgot password link to recover it.";
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    string providerName = "Google";
                    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    string query = "INSERT INTO Members(Name, Email, ProviderName)values(@gName,@gEmail,@providerName)";
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                        {
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gName", gName);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gEmail", gEmail);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@providerName", providerName);
                            connection.Open();
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Session.Add("GEmail", gEmail);
                            Session.Add("CurrentUserName", gName);
                            Response.Redirect("ExternalRegistration.aspx");
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is GoogleUserOutputData class and Google Login Method

```
 public class GoogleUserOutputData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string given_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
    }
protected void btnGoogleLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var Googleurl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + googleplus_redirect_url + "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&client_id=" + googleplus_client_id;
        Session["Provider"] = "Google";
        Response.Redirect(Googleurl);
    }
```

The exception i am getting is: "The parameterized query '(@gEmail nvarchar(4000))SELECT Email FROM Members where Email=@g' expects the parameter '@gEmail', which was not supplied."

Comment: So what is the problem ? Do you get any compile-time or run-time error ? If so, please state it.

Comment: For starters, this is very wrong: `catch (Exception ex) { }`. *Do* something with the exception. For anything else, we can't know what is wrong. Doesn't it set the variables? Any exception raised?

Comment: Also don't use `async void` use `async Task` unless this is an event handler...

Comment: The problem is the value is not passed to to the global variable.

Comment: Are you awaiting the async task? How do you call the method?

Comment: Then place a breakpoint on `if (serStatus != null)` and check if it is null. Also place a breakpoint on the first `{` of the catch.

Comment: Edit your question, show the json string and the definition of class `GoogleUserOutputData`. It seems the Deserialization is failing. Or you're just swallowing the exception.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the value. The only problem is assigning the values to global variables.

Comment: @RaphaelMutiso so `gName = serStatus.name;` is being hit by a breakpoint ?

Comment: @user3185569 Yes. It seems.

Comment: There is no *it seems* in a breakpoint being hit. Can you show the definition of `gName` and other places where you're using it where it is failing to capture the latest value ?

Comment: @RaphaelMutiso do you use `await getgoogleplususerdataSer()` or you're calling it without the await ?

Comment: @user3185569 I am calling it without await.

Comment: Then put `await` in front of it. Now you are just firing a method without waiting it to finish.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman, putting await gives this error: "Await operator can only be used within an Async method."

Comment: @RaphaelMutiso then mark the method as `async`

Comment: Did you put `async Task<...>` in front of the method as already commented by others? You should really listen to what others tell you...

Comment: @Patrick Hofman. Just do not know how to do it based on my getgoogleplususerdataSer method.

Comment: Why don't you just call `getgoogleplususerdataSer` inside the method `RegisterGoogleUser` and return the values you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to read more about how to use [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx).

If you call `getgoogleplususerdataSer()` without the await keyword, the execution of your block of code continues even before the end of the method.

So:

```
private async Task callingMethod()
{
    getgoogleplususerdataSer();
    Console.WriteLine(gName); // maybe null, runs before the end of previous method.
    Console.WriteLine(gEmail); // maybe  null
}
```

instead:

```
private async Task callingMethod()
{
    await getgoogleplususerdataSer(); // wait for this to end, then continue.
    Console.WriteLine(gName); // null
    Console.WriteLine(gEmail); // null
}
```